# Extracting element/string from a dict list value

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm having some trouble extracting info from a Python object. Basically, using notation like this works to get down to values within a dict I am working with:

```
clean_content['Al38zGKg6YC4']['image']
```

I was expecting to see another nested dict which contained the key/value that I wanted to extract. However, what's there is a list that looks like a dict[image: ![enter image description here][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYSvR.png)]

I'm looking to extract the 'permalink' field from this list, and then tie it back to the page ID in the original dict. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure that is not a dict, from the imate that object looks like a dict.  maybe is a dict _inside_ a list?

Comment: So you're saying ```type(clean_content['Al38zGKg6YC4']['image'])==list```? Sure looks like a dict.

Comment: It looks completely like a dict - but when I check type, it's a list. Hence the huge headscratching on my part.

Comment: can you give us a small sample of the initial data so we can help properly

Answer (score 0):

I came to a working solution as follows: converting the original dictionary into a pandas dataframe, I extracted the column containing the lists of image data. Each of these lists contained URLs for multiple images, so I extracted the one required using dicts:

```
image_df_temp = {}
image_df_url = {}

for i in range(len(image_df_base.index)):
    image_df_temp[i] = pd.DataFrame(image_df_base.image[i])
    image_df_url[i] = image_df_temp[i].iloc[0]
```

Finally, I edited the dicts missing the required metadata using .get:

```
for i in range(len(image_df_base.index)):
    image_df_url[i] = image_df_url[i].get('permalink', "No image available")
```